# getting IOException: Premature EOF when running import.io

Tags: import.io

I have created a crawler using import.io
the first issue I faced was that import.io could not identify the data on the webpage after clicking "Detect Optimal Settings".
It asks "is the data you want to extract still in the browser?"
As the data is not highlighted I click no. Even then the data is still not highlighted. The same thing happens with the extractor.
I proceeded with the issue, by clicking yes when it asked "is the data you want to extract still in the browser?" even though the data was not highlighted.
I went on to build the crawler and it works fine. 
I put around 15K urls in the start url with page depth 0.

What happens is that out of 15K pages, around 10% of the pages are not crawled. I checked the log file and it shows `IOException: Premature EOF` against the rows that were not crawled.

If I manually go to that page in a browser, the page loads fine and is in the same format in which I trained the crawler. I even tried to train the pages which showed this error, but that doesnt help.

How can I get around this error?

Comment: Hi, this error is related to there being a null value in the string. This could be happening because the data structure of the website it not being identified. When you use the Detect Optimal Setting feature, this is to capture if you are going to need javascript to get data from the website. If the data is not available with either option, it could be that the website needs cookies or something more advanced. If you would supply me with your GUID, I would be happy to see if there is any troubleshooting I can do.

Comment: i dont know where exactly i can get the GUID. 
i got this one on the address bar of the app. id=a80fa302-9ad7-4245-8023-878d893a2e25

Comment: I would recommend emailing support@import.io and include your log file. This will be better as the issue may just be site specific.

Comment: the support is not helpful at all. i had already sent an email regarding this. they take along time to reply. and when they reply its a tutorial they send which is not even relevant to the issue

Comment: I am sorry that our support did not get back to you promptly. I would be happy to look at it for you. Import support is a free service so sometimes it can take a little bit of time to respond as we respond to all tickets in order. With issues like the above you are having, it will be difficult to troubleshoot without additional information, like your log files.

Comment: how do you want me to send you the log file? i have already sent one in the email i sent to support@import.io

Comment: Hi, I have received your ticket! I am looking at it now. Will be in touch shortly when I have a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I responded to your support ticket, thought it would be good to put that information here as well. This error is most likely related to the website detecting that you are using a crawler and blocking the URLs. I would suggest rerunning the crawler with increased "pause between pages", since you are passing through so many pages, in order for the site not to block you.

Comment: i checked this. the website is not blocking, correct me if i am not wrong. coz i am able to open the page link which has failed to be crawled, from my browser. if the website was blocking then it should have blocked my browser aswell. i am not sure if it is only blocking the import.io app

Comment: Yes, I should have clarified further, it will be blocking the import app. When you are passing so many pages through at once, the website most likely caught on.